# Color variance between mac os and windows

Tags: css

I'm working on a fairly big web project. The site features a colorful landscape background. I'm about to include different CSS files for mac and windows because of the severe color variance. Am I out of my mind? Too picky? Am I the only one who would consider this?

Comment: What exactly is showing the variance, the images or the CSS colours? What browsers are you testing this in? Does the background image have a colour profile attached?

Comment: are you using one monitor or two different ones? is the colour profile on mac and windows set to the same one?

Comment: Both CSS and images are showing variance. Mac is a brand new 27" iMac. Windows is a 4 year old Dell laptop. I realise the monitors have a lot to do with the variance....but this is drastic. I guess about 85% of users will be using 4 year old windows laptops, so should I just style for that?

Comment: What browsers are you testing this with and what version of CSS are you using? There are certain to be rendering discrepancies between browsers.

Comment: Tried it in Chrome, FF and IE 7. Slight discrepencies between them but nothing major.

Comment: I'm using rgb(184, 144, 3).  On Mac it is a orange-ish Yellow,  on windows it is a brown-ish Yellow.  To test, I have 2 mac books, one running Windows and one running OSX, each with a second monitor. There is absolutely a difference between the colors on the two OSs.  Also, the differences are consistent on the same machine between various browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

... I'd say outside of the good old 'web safe' colors all bets are off. Not sure what role color profiles will help here (just don't know), you might have to go for a 'middle of the road' approach. I'd design for the baseline of your audience. Is there any difference between JPG's and PNG's when it comes to photographs?

Comment: jpgs and pngs are showing up pretty consitently. My baseline audience is definitely windows by a mile.....but it looks so pretty on my mac :(

Comment: :-) Have to go with the baseline, sorry